# Building robotlocomotion drake-distro

Tags: java, installation, cygwin, robotics

I have 64 bit win 8 and installed cygwin 64(and jdk 8).
when I use make command this pops up:
error message

[image]
the distro' link is [drake distro](https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake)
Thanks in advance

Comment: It might help to be more specific about what this project is, and/or where it's from. Is it from here: https://github.com/lcm-proj/lcm ? If so, specific build issues with building from source might get quicker responses if you create an issue ticket on the project?

Comment: I have added that.

Comment: Added error message image.